# How to buy a flat with a loan from NRI friend

Tags: mortgage, india, loans, home-loan

I am intending to buy a flat worth 60 laks rupees in India, I am an Indian Citizen. I have 35 laks rupees in my bank (sale proceeds of a flat) and I want to fund the remaining 25 laks as;

- 15 laks from bank loan and
- 10 laks from a NRI friend.

Can this be done. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a loan from NRI. The funds have to come from specified account [NRE or inward remittance]. Maximum rate of interest should be less than RBI rate plus 2%. The loan repayment should be in your friends NRO account. Please see the [guidelines here](https://rbi.org.in/scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Mode=0&Id=10191)

Comment: Should "_cannot be more than 2% of RBI rate_" be "_cannot be more than 2% **above** RBI rate_"?

Comment: @TripeHound Thanks. Reworded to bring the clarity.